# WEBIX JET uses only single webix.ui?

Tags: webix

I realized that all the modules are added in single `webix.ui` and [generated page](http://webix.com/snippet/bb4f6b32):

```
// views/start
var start = {
  template:"Start page"
};

// views/top
var header = {
    type:"header", template: 'TEST'
};

var menu = {
    view:"menu",
    width:180, layout:"y", select:true,
    template:"<span class='webix_icon fa-#icon#'></span> #value# ",
    data:[
        { value:"DashBoard",        id:"start",     icon:"envelope-o" },
        { value:"Data",             id:"data",      icon:"briefcase" }
    ]
};

var ui = {
    type:"line", cols:[
        { type:"clean", css:"app-left-panel", padding:10, margin:20, borderless:true, rows: [ header, menu ]},
        { type:"clean", css:"app-right-panel", padding:4, rows:[ start ]}

    ]
};

webix.ui( ui );
```

So, how to create a menu from [this example](http://docs.webix.com/samples/28_sidemenu/02_left.html) with **WEBIX JET**? It uses double `webix.ui`